# How can I show a tooltip on top a button whenever hover it?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I want to show a tooltip on top whenever hover a button in Angular2.

Do we need to write a directive for this?

I don't want to use Material UI for this.

Looking for something reusable

Comment: Setting the `title` property of the button does not do what you want? You want to have more control on the tooltip position?

Comment: Yes title works. But i want more control

Answer (score 6):

If you want a simple tooltip, only HTML and CSS can do.

Simple styling, I'll let you do your own :)

```css
button {
  padding: 12px; 
  background: orange;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<button data-tooltip="Hovered content">Hover me !</button>
```

Comment: Good. Thanks. I am looking for something reusuable. So if its something like a directive then i will feel better

Comment: As far as I'm a big fan of Angular, unless you have other requirements, I will advise you to use this method. If you want to give your tooltip parameters, you should use a directive, but if you only want a tooltip, you should stick to HTML and CSS. I will make another answer to make you a directive if you want, but keep in mind that it is heavier to have a directive rather than a very simple tooltip.